# How i change remove the xampp password to no password?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a site and it shows an error in the password. I don't want to face such a problem, so how can I remove the current password to no password.

Comment: phpmyadmin password right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
2. Open the file [XAMPP Installation Path] / phpmyadmin /
   config.inc.php in your favorite text editor.
3. Search for the string `$cfg\['Servers'\]\[$i\]['password'] = 'password';` and
   change it to like this, `$cfg\['Servers'\]\[$i\]['password'] ='';` Here the ‘’ is what we set to the root user using the SQL query.
4. Now all set to go. Save the config.inc.php file and restart the
   XAMPP server.

This should solve your problem.

Refer [source](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/) for more details.

Comment: read point 6 in the given link `If you refresh the page, you will be getting a error message. This is because the phpMyAdmin configuration file is not aware of our newly set root passoword. To do this we have to modify the phpMyAdmin config file.`

Comment: Thank you mate, I changed as per your suggestion.

Comment: There is no string like $cfg\['Servers'\]\[$i\]['password'] = 'password'; in config.inc.php

Comment: `ctrl+f` `password` string in that file

Comment: Thanks i find that

Comment: @WaqarAhmadYousafzai Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.